# Query to find records with last two approval date

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have two tables, `Plan` and `Plan_Log`. Their structure looks like below:

Table: `Plan`

```
Id  PlanName  PlanApprovalDate         PlanStatus
--  --------  -----------------------  ----------
1   abc       18-04-2014 15:48:22.790  A
2   def       19-07-2014 15:48:22.790  A
```

Table: `Plan_Log`

```
Id  PlanName  PlanApprovalDate
--  --------  -----------------------
1   abc       18-04-2014 15:48:22.790
2   abc       17-04-2014 15:48:22.790
3   abc       15-04-2014 15:48:22.790 
4   def       19-07-2014 15:48:22.790
5   def       18-07-2014 15:48:22.790
6   def       17-07-2014 15:48:22.790
```

From these records I want to retrieve each plan with its two most recent `PlanApprovalDate` records. Also, I need to make sure that these plans are active ones (`PlanStatus`). So my final list should retrieve:

```
ID  PlanName  PlanApprovalDate
--  --------  -----------------------
1   abc       18-04-2014 15:48:22.790
2   abc       17-04-2014 15:48:22.790
3   def       18-07-2014 15:48:22.790 
4   def       19-07-2014 15:48:22.790
```

How can I achieve this result?

I am using Sybase ASE 12.5.4

Comment: What version of Sybase are you using?  In particular, does it support window functions such as `row_number()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` quite easily (supported by some versions of Sybase):

```
select id, plan_name, PlanApprovalDate
from (select pl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by plan_name order by PlanApprovalDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from plan_log pl
     ) pl
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Without windows functions, you can do this in different ways.  Here is a method with a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select id, plan_name, PlanApprovalDate
from plan_log pl
where 2 >= (select count(*)
            from plan_log pl2
            where pl2.plan_name = pl.plan_name and
                  pl2.PlanApprovalDate >= pl.PlanApprovalDate
           );
```

Comment: I have slightly modified my question. I have added one flag (PlanStatus). I need to check for only active plans. I am using Sybase  12.5.4 version.

Comment: @user3049531 . . . Just add a `where` clause to the queries.  For the second one, add the `where` clause to both the subquery and the outer query.

Comment: Can you provide the query.